# Prove that there are infinitely many composite numbers in 10^n-9

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Consider the sequence {1, 91, 991, 9991, 99991, ...}
Prove that infinitely many of its elements are composite numbers.

Comment: No attempt? Please, add your thoughts about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ be sufficiently large so that $10^n-9>1$ ($n=2$ suffices). Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $10^n-9$. Then $p$ divides $10^{n+k\cdot(p-1)}-9$ for all $k\geqslant0$, by little Fermat. Since $10^n-9$ is increasing, $10^{n+k\cdot(p-1)}-9$ is composite for $k>0$.

**Note**
The same argument works for proving that $(a_1^n+a_2^n+\cdots+a_k^n+c)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ contains infinitely many composites (provided the $a_l$'s are so that the sequence is eventually increasing). One could generalise even further by admitting polynomials as coefficients for the terms $a_l^n$.

Comment: Using FLT to construct composites from not-necessarily composites in such sequences gives slightly more impressive results, with almost no work: [Show that for every k$\in \mathbb N$ $2^n+3^n-1,2^n+3^n-2,...,2^n+3^n-k$ are all composite for some $n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556358)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: How can you rewrite the expression if $n$ is even?